# OneDrive for Business giving 'Credentials Needed' error on every file

Tags: microsoft-office, sync, onedrive

Since changing my password, OneDrive for Business (Office 2013) will no longer sync any files.

It is showing sync errors against every file saying ‘Credentials Needed’ when I click any of these sync errors, it opens internet explorer and takes me to my files on Office 365. It still syncs the whole folder structure, but not any of the files.

I have tried the following to try and fix this problem:

- Done a ‘repair’ on OneDrive
- Stopped syncing all libraries and re-added them
- Logged out/in to Office 365
- Removed all credentials from Windows Credentials Manager
- Unlinked the account from Outlook
- Uninstalled/reinstalled OneDrive
- Applied all available updates for Windows & Office

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the problem for me:

Uninstall Office 2013 update KB3085566.

For some reason, this security update was causing my problems. I uninstalled it, rebooted and the problem went away.

You can follow [instructions for uninstalling an update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/remove-update#1TC=windows-7%20How%20to%20uninstall%20an%20update)

> 1. Open Installed Updates by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Programs, and then,
>      under Programs and Features, clicking View installed updates.
> 2. Click the update that you want to remove, and then click Uninstall.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>      confirmation.

Comment: Saved my life! :-)