# OneDrive for Business giving 'Credentials Needed' error

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, sync, onedrive, office365

Since using OneDrive for Business (ODfB) client, I do encounter an unexpected behaviour that seems to be spread widely. However, available solutions did not help. Its triggers are not known to me precisely, yet may include Office or Windows updates, respectively change of credentials. I wish to continue using ODfB client.

My system operates on Windows 7 Enterprise with Office 365 Click-to-run edition (currently version 16.0.6741.2048), however the issue was present with Office 15 already.

I am trying to sync ~1.800 files within ~300 directories, totalling ~3.600 MiB. A massive reduction in number of files or split-archiving all of them is not feasible for me. Biggest files are ~200 MiB, while the web interface allowed me to upload ~2.500 MiB per file (which is removed meanwhile). Currently, ~1.008 "GB" of 1.024 "GB" total storage are being free.

First synchronization is always fine and multiple changes to files may be synced flawlessly.

This time, uploading 18 .7z files around ~200 MiB each using the ODfB client triggered the issue, previous times it was small-sized .xlsx files or .txt files. The issue is one or multiple sync error(s), asking me to "Please enter your credentials"; however, there is no button or form allowing to do so, like when Office is installed freshly and asks for credentials the first time. This happens at some point in time, seemingly random, even without updates applied or credentials changed meanwhile.

From this point on, no more files will be uploaded to the Web, however new folders will be created but left empty.

I tried all [solutions proposed to me via Google, mostly those from TechNet and StackExchange](https://www.google.de/search?q=onedrive+business+please+enter+credentials). Especially, I tried the following, multiple times and for each of various Office versions:

- Update Office
- Repair Office
- Repair ODfB
- Stop sync and re-add folder manually
- [Look for Office update KB3085566 to deinstall](https://superuser.com/questions/990270/onedrive-for-business-giving-credentials-needed-error-on-every-file) (applies to MSI edition only)
- Clear OdfB file cache
- Remove all or Office-only credentials using Windows' Credentials Manager 
  (followed by reboot and re-add)
- Pause and continue sync
- Restart computer like a hundred times

After resyncing ODfB, my files are are synchronous between local and Web. If I add some files to be uploaded to the Cloud, this may or may not happen, at any point again provoking the enter-credentials behaviour.

How can I fix this (permanently) to continue using synchronization between my local files and SharePoint folders?

Cheers,
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Office 365 did not update itself completely, excluding the current version of OneDrive client. After visiting the OneDrive Web site, [downloading](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/) and installing it by myself, I am now using the "Next Generation Sync Client" [that Microsoft announced in December 2015](https://blogs.office.com/2015/12/16/onedrive-for-business-update-on-storage-plans-and-next-generation-sync-client/).

It was able to sync all my folders and files without an issue: Case closed.